# What would make a good temporary joint filler between vinyl tile?

Tags: grout, vinyl-flooring, joints

I'm living with the peal and stick home depot tile that could be installed either grouted or groutless.

I chose the latter.

I have lots of dirt catchers now.

Yesterday I was patching the walls prepatory to painting.  I dropped a big glob of joint compound on the floor.  On cleaning it up, I notice that if filled the cracks nicely.

"Hmm" thought I.  "It's below the surface so it doesn't actually get stepped on.  Everytime I wash the floor, I'll lose a film of it.  I may end up having to touch it up every so often."

Now the instructions with the tile said "Only use our magic vinyl grout.  do not use regular grout."  And I can see that.  Regular grout is meant to be used with ceramic which is much more brittle.

Now I'm pretty sure that joint compound is not the best material for this.  And the reviews say that the original acrylic ground is a PITA to work with.

What would make a good temporary joint filler between vinyl tile?  This floor is on my 'replace the floor' list, but it will likely be 2-3 years.  Meanwhile I'm tired of cleaning dirt out of cracks.

Thoughts:  Vinyl is a pretty non-stick surface.  I've had little problem getting paint drips off it even a day later.  So a candidate needs to be able to make a mechanical bond with the surface.

It doesn't need to be very strong.  It's not the wear surface.

Ideally it washes well, even if it erodes slightly.

It shouldn't be too brittle.  Vinyl flexes some.

Lime based plaster?  Straight lime putty?

Add some fiberglass strand re-enforcement?  Cabosil?

Comment: Two thoughts: One, you'll spend more time trying to fill in 3 miles of cracks than you will cleaning the floor over the next couple years. Honestly, let the dirt where it is and just clean the tile surface. Voila, 
 black grout. Two, even if you did find something and take the time to install it, it'll probably end up black anyway.

Comment: Plus one for writing in poetry style and quoting yourself to boot. Until I know otherwise I'll assume that you're a self-published fiction writer. :D The question itself? Meh.

Comment: It sounds like you really need the vinyl for the flexibility. It might be a PITA, but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Filling is actually quite fast.  I've laid tile elsewhere in the house, and have a grout float.  And it's only 2 linear feet per square foot of tile.  So about 1200 feet total. I've done a 10 square foot area by the entrance.  We'll see how it deals with the dogs wet muddy paws.  And no, I'm not an unpublished fiction writer.  But... ex school teacher, and current web spinner.